# FLINK1.8 , ERROR INFO : state is larger than the maximum permitted memory-backed state. use RocksDBStateBackend not useful

Tags: apache-flink

**I'm running hibench's flinkbench   with FLINK1.8**

**Stateful Wordcount (wordcount)**

This workload counts words cumulatively received from Kafka every few seconds. This tests the stateful operator performance and Checkpoint/Acker cost in the streaming frameworks.

**RUN COMMAND** :  flink run   -yjm 1gb -ytm 1gb -ys 1 -p 1 -m yarn-cluster -c  xxxxx

**ERROR INFO** :

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Size of the state is larger than the maximum permitted memory-backed state. Size=1766987 , maxSize=51200 . Consider using a different state backend, like the File System State backend.
at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.memory.MemCheckpointStreamFactory.checkSize(MemCheckpointStreamFactory.java:64)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.memory.MemCheckpointStreamFactory$MemoryCheckpointOutputStream.closeAndGetBytes(MemCheckpointStreamFactory.java:145)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.memory.MemCheckpointStreamFactory$MemoryCheckpointOutputStream.closeAndGetHandle(MemCheckpointStreamFactory.java:126)
at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.RocksDBStateUploader.uploadLocalFileToCheckpointFs(RocksDBStateUploader.java:136)
at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.RocksDBStateUploader.lambda$createUploadFutures$0(RocksDBStateUploader.java:99)
at org.apache.flink.util.function.CheckedSupplier.lambda$unchecked$0(CheckedSupplier.java:34)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1604)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.DirectExecutorService.execute(DirectExecutorService.java:211)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.asyncSupplyStage(CompletableFuture.java:1618)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(CompletableFuture.java:1843)
at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.RocksDBStateUploader.createUploadFutures(RocksDBStateUploader.java:100)
at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.RocksDBStateUploader.uploadFilesToCheckpointFs(RocksDBStateUploader.java:70)
at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.snapshot.RocksIncrementalSnapshotStrategy$RocksDBIncrementalSnapshotOperation.uploadSstFiles(RocksIncrementalSnapshotStrategy.java:419)
at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.snapshot.RocksIncrementalSnapshotStrategy$RocksDBIncrementalSnapshotOperation.callInternal(RocksIncrementalSnapshotStrategy.java:315)
at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.snapshot.RocksIncrementalSnapshotStrategy$RocksDBIncrementalSnapshotOperation.callInternal(RocksIncrementalSnapshotStrategy.java:258)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.AsyncSnapshotCallable.call(AsyncSnapshotCallable.java:75)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.FutureUtils.runIfNotDoneAndGet(FutureUtils.java:391)
```

I  had   use   RocksDBStateBackend.  and  the rate of data transmission is as low as 100 per second.  but none of them seem to work.

**SOURCE CODE:**

```
public class WordCount extends StreamBase {

  @Override
  public void processStream(final FlinkBenchConfig config) throws Exception {
    final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
    env.setBufferTimeout(config.bufferTimeout);
    env.enableCheckpointing(config.checkpointDuration);
    **//use RocksDBStateBackend**
    env.setStateBackend(new RocksDBStateBackend("hdfs:///fink-checkpoints", true));
    createDataStream(config);
    DataStream<Tuple2<String, String>> dataStream = env.addSource(getDataStream());
    dataStream
        .map(new MapFunction<Tuple2<String, String>, Tuple2<String, Tuple2<String, Integer>>>() {
          @Override
          public Tuple2<String, Tuple2<String, Integer>> map(Tuple2<String, String> input) throws Exception {
            String ip = UserVisitParser.parse(input.f1).getIp();
            //map record to <browser, <timeStamp, 1>> type
            return new Tuple2<String, Tuple2<String, Integer>>(ip, new Tuple2<String, Integer>(input.f0, 1));
          }
        })
        .keyBy(0)
        .map(new RichMapFunction<Tuple2<String, Tuple2<String, Integer>>, Tuple2<String, Tuple2<String, Integer>>>() {
          private transient ValueState<Integer> sum;

          @Override
          public Tuple2<String, Tuple2<String, Integer>> map(Tuple2<String, Tuple2<String, Integer>> input) throws Exception {
            int currentSum = sum.value();
            currentSum += input.f1.f1;
            sum.update(currentSum);
            KafkaReporter kafkaReporter = new KafkaReporter(config.reportTopic, config.brokerList);
            kafkaReporter.report(Long.parseLong(input.f1.f0), System.currentTimeMillis());
            return new Tuple2<String, Tuple2<String, Integer>>(input.f0, new Tuple2<String, Integer>(input.f1.f0, currentSum));
          }

          @Override
          public void open(Configuration config) {
            ValueStateDescriptor<Integer> descriptor =
                new ValueStateDescriptor<Integer>(
                    "count", // the state name
                    TypeInformation.of(new TypeHint<Integer>() {
                    }), // type information
                    0); // default value of the state, if nothing was set
            sum = getRuntimeContext().getState(descriptor);
          }
        });
    env.execute("Word Count Job");}
```

Ive tried multiple variations of this, but none of them seem to work. Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would recommend updating your Flink version regardless. Version 1.8 is quite old and no longer supported by the Flink community at all.

Comment: Thank you , although I do not know the reason, but after upgrading to 1.14 to solve the problem。

Answer (score 0):

Is it getting `-yjm 1gb -ytm 1gb` properly? I would try with `-yjm 1024 -ytm 1024` since it expects this value to be in megabytes.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I solved this problem by upgrading.